# How to increment the filename if file already exists?

Tags: ios, swift

How to increment filename if the file already exists? Here's the code that I am using:

```
let count: Int = 1
var newFileName = ""

let path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as String
let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path)
let filePath = url.URLByAppendingPathComponent("MyDoc.pdf").path!
let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
if fileManager.fileExistsAtPath(filePath) {
    print("FILE AVAILABLE")
    newFileName =  "MyDoc\(count).pdf"

} else {
    print("FILE NOT AVAILABLE")
}
```

MyDoc.pdf, MyDoc(1).pdf, MyDoc(5).pdf then how to increment?

Comment: is there any kind of error !

Comment: Use a `while` statement!

Comment: explain your question !

Comment: What does "How to increment filename if the file already exists?" mean?

Answer (score 6):

**Swift 4 Solution :**

```
func copyFile(fromPathString:String, toPathString:String) {

    let myManager = FileManager.default
    let fromPath : URL = URL(fileURLWithPath: fromPathString)
    var toPath = toPathString + fromPath.lastPathComponent
    let filename = (URL(fileURLWithPath: toPath)).lastPathComponent
    let fileExt  = (URL(fileURLWithPath: toPath)).pathExtension
    var fileNameWithoSuffix : String!
    var newFileName : String!
    var counter = 0


    if filename.hasSuffix(fileExt) {
        fileNameWithoSuffix = String(filename.prefix(filename.count - (fileExt.count+1)))
    }

    while myManager.fileExists(atPath: toPath) {
        counter += 1
        newFileName =  "\(fileNameWithoSuffix!)_\(counter).\(fileExt)"
        let newURL = URL(fileURLWithPath:toPathString).appendingPathComponent(newFileName).path
        toPath = newURL
    }

    try! myManager.copyItem(atPath: fromPathString, toPath: toPath)

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a  while statement to increase the counter until you find a file name that isn't taken:

```
guard var filePath = url.URLByAppendingPathComponent("MyDoc.pdf").path else {
    // force-unwrapping is not the answer! Handle error
    return
}

let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()

var counter = 0

while fileManager.fileExistsAtPath(filePath) {
    counter += 1

    newFileName =  "MyDoc(\(counter)).pdf"
    let newURL = url.URLByAppendingPathComponent(newFileName) 

    guard let newPath = newURL.path else {
        // Handle error (shouldn't happen anyway)
        return
    }
    path = newPath // Try again...
}
```

**Note:** I haven't tried to compile this code. It might have some minor errors.

Answer (score 1):

in this code you every time create MyDoc1.pdf

if you want every time new pdf file so you get number of file(count) exists at location and increment   number of file(count) + 1